# Recover mysql using data folder

Tags: mysql, restore, recovery, disaster-recovery, ibdata

One of our MySQL servers died but somehow we were able to recover all the files from it. This server was a slave at one time however we stopped it being a slave so we could use it for housekeeping tasks and reports, etc.

Can someone tell me how to recover with this?

I now have these files and a backup of my.cnf

```
    ll /root/home/recovered/mysql/
    -rw-r----- 1 root root          117 Jun  1 09:30 rabney-relay-bin.000001
    -rw-r----- 1 root root           26 Jun  1 09:30 rabney-relay-bin.index
    -rw-r----- 1 root root 113055367168 Jun  1 10:42 ibdata1
    -rw-r----- 1 root root   1073741824 Jun  1 09:33 ib_logfile0
    -rw-r----- 1 root root   1073741824 Jun  1 09:33 ib_logfile1
    drwx------ 2 root root         4096 Jun  1 09:30 mysql
    drwx------ 2 root root        16384 Jun  1 09:30 production_copy
    -rw-r----- 1 root root   3253518648 Jun  1 09:32 slowquery.log
    drwx------ 2 root root         4096 Jun  1 09:30 test
```

I've been reading articles on Google regarding this but not sure how to do it yet.

Comment: Questions : 1) Do you have anything in `/var/lib/mysql` right now ? 2) Do you have an existing `/etc/my.cnf` ?

Comment: No. Its a new server. So I just installed mysql.

Comment: Is there a `/var/lib/mysql` folder with similar contents ???

Comment: no. There is no /var/lib/mysql.
I was wondering if I should create a /var/lib/mysql and copy all files from /root/home/recovered/mysql to this new directory and also replace my.cnf with the backup copy and then try to start mysql server? will that work?

Answer (score 0):

STEP 01

Go see if MySQL is running on the Server. Run this

```
service mysql status
```

If the status says `SUCCESS! MySQL running (some number)` then shutdown mysql

```
service mysql stop
```

STEP 02

Run `ls -l /etc/my.cnf`. If the file exists, rename it with `mv /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf.backup`

Then, copy your `my.cnf` into `/etc`

STEP 03

See if you have a previous mysql setup

```
ls -l /var/lib/mysql
```

If you do, do this

```
mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.old
mkdir /var/lib/mysql
```

Then, copy your `/root/home/recovered/mysql` into `/var/lib/mysql`

STEP 04

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

STEP 05

```
service mysql start
```

GIVE IT A TRY !!!